# Facebook javascript events not fired any way i turn it

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK with my site, there is an option there to set events when user login/logout from Facebook so i can show him notifications in my website.
can't manage it to work, tried everything, also using **offline_access** permission.

here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="blabla" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="blabla" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="blabla" /> 
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://XXX/" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXX" />
        <title>Facebook Notifier</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/global.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="my_div">
    </div>
</a>
</body></html>
```

here is my js code:

```
FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXX',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        oauth : true, // enables OAuth 2.0
        channelUrl : 'http://XXX/channelUrl'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            connected = true;
        }
        else{
            connected = false;
        }
    }, true);

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) connected = true;
        else connected = false;
    });
```

in the end of this js code i have a function that run every few seconds checking the connection variable, its a global one. and it not changed i tried to login/logout from facebook and no event fires.
only when i refresh the page i can get the user status.
in firefox firebug console i get the message (also tried in chrome, ie):
**uncaught exception: Error: https://www.facebook.com Proxy.InstallTrigger**
i tried to solve it by doing everything i can find about this error in google and also in stackoverflow and still not working.
btw: when i wrote XXX in the original files its my url or my appid.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've always been a bit skeptical about the `auth.` events the Facebook fires so in your case I'd prob just setup a poller myself to check the auth status of the connected users. Like this:

```
var connected;

FB.init({
    appId  : 'XXX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth : true, // enables OAuth 2.0
    channelUrl : 'http://XXX/channelUrl'
});


FB.getLoginStatus(handleUserStateChange);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleUserStateChange);

function handleUserStateChange(response) {
    connected = !!response.authResponse;
}

setInterval(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleUserStateChange, true);
}, 10000)   // poll every 10 seconds
```

Also as you defined `status: true` in the `FB.init` config object you don't need to pass the second parameter to `FB.getLoginStatus` at the start as that forces a check to Facebook instead of reading from the stored variable (which is already the latest information as we just initd).

Comment: Can you explain a bit by why you're using a double-"not" operator?: `connected = !!response.authResponse;`  Are you just using this as a "lazy typecast"?

Comment: BTW, +1 because polling `FB.getLoginStatus()` did fix my problem.  I get the feeling it's not the "right" way to do it, but it does work!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a variable scope problem with `connected`.

Something like this might help:

```
var connected; // define/initialize connected variable outside functions
FB.init({
    appId  : 'XXX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth : true, // enables OAuth 2.0
    channelUrl : 'http://XXX/channelUrl'
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        connected = true;
    }
    else{
        connected = false;
    }
}, true);

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if(response.authResponse) connected = true;
    else connected = false;
});
```

I would use `console.log()` from within your functions that respond to subscribed events to see what is really happening (or not happening).  Then write your real code based on what `console.log()` tells you.

Comment: i mention in the question that i have connected as global variable as you said. i also tried the console.log() thing. nothing logged there. only in firefox firebug i get an uncaught exception when trying to login/logout facebook, in chrome firebug i get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing `FB.Event.subscribe` in a function that is invoked on document ready event:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=...";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

$("document").ready(function(){
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
      });
});
</script>
```

Or [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete) there is another example of making sure that FB is initialised before you do any invocations.

Comment: If using jQuery, why not also use jQuery.getScript() to get the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I'm all new into FB development and ran into the same issue a couple days ago.

I tried pretty much all answers and solutions that are out there but nothing 
worked out. The damn event wouldn't want to fire no matter what I did in my 
latest VS project. However I remembered getting this to work in my first VS project
where I followed a tutorial on the same matter. After a while I checked that initial project and to my surprise it fired there and not in my other one.

Finally I realized that the **Canvas Url on FB (app settings) was the culprit** :
h t t p: // localhost:15497/

It was set to my localhost with the port used in my other project. I changed the port number and suddenly it also worked in my other project.

**Make sure that the canvas url in the FB app settings matches where your Visual Studio runs the app. Also change the value once you deploy your web app.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're in 2022 wondering why it won't fire. Enable 3rd party cookies, this worked for me.