# authResponseChange not firing

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

I have the following code, it works for a while then after a while I cannot get the authResponseChange event to fire anymore. I have deleted all of my cookies, deauthorized the app and re-added it. How do I handle this event?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleResponseChange);

    };

    function handleResponseChange(response) {
        document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('connect');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you block third party cookies?

Answer (score 1):

this must solve your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212668/facebook-javascript-events-not-fired-any-way-i-turn-it

```
var connected;

FB.init({
    appId  : 'XXX',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth : true, // enables OAuth 2.0
    channelUrl : 'http://XXX/channelUrl'
});


FB.getLoginStatus(handleUserStateChange);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleUserStateChange);

function handleUserStateChange(response) {
    connected = !!response.authResponse;
}

setInterval(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleUserStateChange, true);
}, 10000)   // poll every 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the sdk loading in your code. Are you sure you are initializing it?

```
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```